# SBT cannot find a package on JCenter

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, jcenter, akka-persistence

I'm trying to use `akka-persistence-inmemory` package from JCenter repository, but I've got an error.

build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
val akka_version = "2.5.17"

resolvers ++= Seq(
    Resolver.jcenterRepo
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.github.dnvriend" % "akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11" % "2.5.15.1" % Test
    // some other deps here
)
```

Error:

```
[warn] ==== jitpack: tried
[warn]   https://jitpack.io/com/github/dnvriend/akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11/2.5.15.1/akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11-2.5.15.1.pom
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dnvriend/akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11/2.5.15.1/akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11-2.5.15.1.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.dnvriend#akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11;2.5.15.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.github.dnvriend:akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11:2.5.15.1 (..\foo\build.sbt#L19-51)
[warn]        +- default:foo_2.12:0.1
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.dnvriend#akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11;2.5.15.1: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the library published on the dnvriend bintray repo

https://bintray.com/dnvriend/maven/akka-persistence-inmemory/

```
resolvers += "dnvriend" at "http://dl.bintray.com/dnvriend/maven"
```

The jcenter repo is not updated with the latest versions of the library.